# Vaadin Set Image as background

Tags: java, css

I am trying to implement a background image on my webpage but it does not work.

here the code for the css:

```
backgroundimage {
 body{
       background: url("common/images/blue.jpg");
    }
```

}

Here is the implementing code:

```
public class LogInView extends VerticalLayout implements View {


           private Navigator navigator;

             TextField txtusername = new TextField("Username: ");
             PasswordField txtpassword = new PasswordField("Password: ");
            Image image = null;
             JDBCConnectionPool connectionPool;

            public LogInView() {
                setStyleName("backgroundimage");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css (without body selector):

```
.backgroundimage {
      background: url("common/images/blue.jpg") !important;
}
```

and inspect layout in browser, ensure image path is correct.

Comment: if i put this backgroundimage on Verticallayout setstyle does it affect only the vertical layout?

Comment: yes, it affect only layouts with same style name (backgroundimage)

Comment: How can i make the panel background not transparent?

Comment: you can inspect layouts in browser and override css style with `!important` css annotation